# Some text or symbol after \item element

Tags: macros, lists

I want add some text after of each element `\item`. For example, I defined a new command

```
\newcommand{\qitem}{\item?} %For the list of questions
\begin{enumerate}
\qitem Some question
\end{enumerate}
```

I want to get such as

> "1. Some question?"

But, the output looks like

> "1. ?Some question"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question needs some clarification, but take a look on the `enumitem` package for example

Comment: The OP wants to add something at the end of the item contents.

Comment: The question mark belongs to the text, so I would simply type it in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to preserve the original interface design, i.e. to say `\qitem Some question` in contrast to `\qitem{Some question}` (as @cfr proposed) you could use the end-of-line char to delimit the argument of `\qitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\qitem{\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12 \qitem@}
\bgroup\catcode`\^^M=12 %
  \gdef\qitem@#1^^M{\item #1?\endgroup}%
\egroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\qitem Some question
\qitem Some other question
\item Not a question
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\qitem[1]{\item #1?}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \qitem{Is this a question}
    \item This is an answer.
    \qitem{Was that a question}
    \qitem{Can this question not be answered}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: questions and answers]

Since you've not provided a Minimum Working Example, I don't know how well this fits with your class etc. However, you should hopefully be able to adapt it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution where you do not need to change the syntax (i.e., you can continue to use `\item bla` instead of `\item{bla}`, like [cfr's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220361/34813)) and pass *the whole content of the item* to the macro (instead of only the current line, like [Ruben's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220366/34813)). This gives you more flexibility than just adding something at the beginning or the end of the item content. For example, you can suppress the content altogether and only keep the label.

The main idea is to replace `\item` with something like `}\item\yourcommand{`. This way, everything in between two `\item` is passed to the command. Since we can't use `{` and `}` when we redefine `\item`, we use `\bgroup` and `\egroup`. Also, we can't pass this implicit group directly to a command, but use `\collectbox` instead, which can deal with `\bgroup...\egroup`. Finally, the first and last `\item` couldn't be of the form above. Instead, we redefine `\item` such that it sets `\@openbracket` to true and close any open brackets in the next `\item` or at the end of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{collectbox}

% Say we want to call this command for each item
\newcommand\question[1]{#1?}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@openbracket

% Define environment similar to enumerate where \item's are terminated with "?"
\newenvironment{enumerateq}%
  {%
    \enumerate
    \let\origitem\item
    \def\item{%
      \if@openbracket\egroup\endgroup\fi%
      \origitem
      \begingroup\@openbrackettrue\collectbox*{\question}\bgroup
    }
  }%
  {\if@openbracket\egroup\endgroup\fi%
   \endenumerate}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerateq}
    \item Is this a question
    \item Was that a question% The new line is part of the content of the item. Comment out to suppress space.
    \item Can this question not be answered%
  \end{enumerateq}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Result]